# Trying to standardize exports

Tags: replace, sed, standards, vi, tabs

I am trying to standardize my exports file. I need to remove all spaces and tabs between the first two fields and replace them with two tabs. I am using VI.

So I want to change

/vol/vol1/home1/xxx -rw=admin:app:admhosts

to

/vol/vol1/home1/xxx           -rw=admin:app:admhosts

making the space equil to To two TABS.

I am using VI.

Comment: I think you might have been tripped up with formatting.  Your from and to examples are the same.

Answer (score 1):

Do `:s/[ ^I]\+/^I^I/` for a single line, or `:%s/[ ^I]\+/^I^I/` for the whole file. Note that I mean `^I` to mean you press Ctrl+I

Comment: I've used ^I before, but always forget it. Do you have a link to a quick reference for these special characters in vim?

Comment: I should have mentioned that ^I is Tab. Pressing the Tab key will do just fine. These are not really special vim keys, just standard ones. Any decent ASCII table will give you the info.